# Find $P(Z>1.8)$ and $P(X>4)$ when $Z$ is normal RV and $X$ is a binomial RV.

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

> **Question 1**
>   If $Z\sim N(0,1)$, Find
>   a) $P(Z>1.8)$
>   b) $P(Z >-2.46)$
>   c) $P(Z>2.589)$
>   d) $P(Z<-0.725)$
>   e) $P(Z<-1.63)$
>   f) $P(Z>-0.65)$

**My Solutions:**
$P(Z>1.8) = 0.9461$
$P(Z >-2.46)= 1-0.99305 = 0.00695$
$P(Z>2.589) = 1-0.9952= 0.0048$
$P(Z<-0.725)= 1-0.7657=0.2343$
$P(Z<-1.63) = 1-0.9484 = 0.0516$
$P(Z>0.65) = 1-0.7422 = 0.2578$

*Can you please check these over for me?*

---

> **Question 2**
>   The random variable $X\sim\text{Bin}(6,0.45)$. Find
>   $P(X>4)$
>   $P(X=6)$
>   $P(X≤3)$

*Can someone please help me with question 2?* I tried researching and everything and still can't find a solution to answering this question.

Thank you.

Comment: Please indicate what you have tried with Question 2. Simply saying you've tried everything doesn't clarify where you are stuck or what you've tried. This information will let others better tailor their answer to your situation and background. It will also show them you are interested in your question and not just looking for homework help - StackExchange is not a homework site.

Comment: For question 1 you got the first two wrong (double check the direction of your inequality) and the remaining four correct.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: P(Z>1.8) = 1-0.8599= 0.1401 & P(Z >-2.46) = 0.99305

Comment: First one is wrong, second one is right.

Comment: How?  P(Z>a) = 1-P(Z<a)

Comment: To reach someone, use the @ if it is not the person whose post you are commenting on. Yes, $P(Z>1.8) = 1-P(Z<1.8)$, but $P(Z<1.8) = 0.9640697$.

Comment: @probablyme can you explain to me how you get that ?

Comment: I used a calculator. If you are using a table, then your answer might be slightly different. You should get a similar or same result if you do that one the same way you did the others. You got those right. So I get that $P(Z>1.8) = 0.03593032$.

Comment: @probablyme Yes I used a table and used the 1.0 section under Z then went across to 8

Comment: Sounds right, except, subtract that from 1. Also, did you figure out the problem below?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37430/discussion-between-ken-and-probablyme).

Answer (score 3):

Under your solutions for the first part, a) and b) are wrong.

Instead of research have you tried calculating anything?

If $X\sim\text{Binomil}(n, p)$, then the probability that $X = k$, for some integer $k$, $0\leq k\leq n$, is
$$P(X = k) = \binom{n}{k} p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}.$$

---

The possible values for your $X$ are $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

Notice that, for $P(X>4)$,
$$\{X>4\}\iff\{X=5\cup X = 6\}$$
and that the events $X=5$ and $X = 6$ are disjoint. Hence
$$P(X > 4) = P(X=5\cup X = 6) = P(X = 5)+P(X=6).$$

Further, for $P(X\leq 3)$,
$$\{X\leq 3\}\iff\{X = 0\cup X = 1\cup X=2\cup X=3\}.$$

You could also notice that $P(X\leq 3)+P(X = 4)+P(X>4) = 1$.

Comment: How do I find the value of k ?

Comment: Well, for the second one, it asks $P(X = 6)$.

Comment: @Ken Just think about it a bit. When the support of $X$ is $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, then: $\mathsf P(X > 4) ~=~ \mathsf P(X=5)+ \mathsf P(X=6)$ and so forth.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Do these sound right?                                                      P(X>4) =  0.060894281 + 0.008303765 = 0.0692                                                                    P(X=6) = 0.0083

Comment: Both seem OK. See output in my Answer. Looks as if you've got the idea.

Answer (score 1):

1. I suppose you are answering these questions using printed normal tables.

Notice that questions of the type $P(Z \le c)$ with $ c > 0$ can be read directly from most printed tables. For a continuous
distribution such as the standard normal $P(Z < c) = (Z \le c).$
Questions involving negative $c$ require the use of symmetry, unless your book has tables that include negative values of $c$.

It is also possible to answer such questions using software and some models of statistical calculators. Here are answers to a few of
the parts of this problem from R statistical software, including
the first two parts, which @IanMiller has said you answered incorrectly, and one that requires averaging two values from a table.
Notice that these answers are given to more places of accuracy than you will get from a printed table. In R software `pbinom` denotes
the CDF of a normal distribution.

```
 1 - pnorm(1.8)   #a
 ## 0.03593032
 1 - pnorm(-2.46) #b
 ## 0.9930531
 pnorm(-.725)     #d average of the following two answers
 ## 0.234226
 pnorm(-.72)
 ## 0.2357625
 pnorm(-.73)
 ## 0.2326951
```

2. I suppose you are supposed to use the binomial formula for these.
   The Answer of @probablyme discusses use of the formula and gives
   you a good start.(+1)

I will give answers from R. You can
use them to check your methods. Here, `pbinom` denotes the CDF and
`pbinom` denotes the PDF, but you have to include parameters
$n$ and $p$ as shown. How many decimal places are $you$ expected to show?

```
 1 - pbinom(4, 6, .45)
 ## 0.06919805
 sum(dbinom(5:6, 6, .45))  # '5:6' includes both 5 and 6
 ## 0.06919805
 dbinom(5, 6, .45) + dbinom(6, 6, .45)
 ## 0.06919805

 dbinom(6, 6, .45)
 ## 0.008303766
 .45^6
 ## 0.008303766

 pbinom(3, 6, .45)
 ## 0.7447361
 sum(dbinom(0:3, 6, .45))
 ## 0.7447361
```

Note: You should probably investigate using software
in this course, if it is not already part of the course.
R software that works on a wide variety of computers
is available free of charge from `r-project.org`.
There is a lot to learn about R; just focus on the parts you need.
If available, many other kinds of statistical software would do as well.